# Update program Script for php sites

Tags: php

I have a web based project written in PHP, this project is being distributed to 5 different servers.

What is the best way to keep these 5 servers updated when I make changes?

I was thinking of writing a cron shell script that would read my source folder and propagate the updates to the seperate servers probably via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

it can't be possible via ftp using cron

Answer (score 0):

I use a script that calls rsync to upload my website from my local machine to the server. Here is an example:

```
rsync -razv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '.settings' --exclude '.buildpath' -e "ssh -l user" --delete ~/workspace/website/ www.example.com:/var/www/
```

I have to exclude the .svn, .settings, & .buildpath files and folders because I don't want those going on the site. My server would be www.example.com. The path on the server would be /var/www and the user would be "user".

The --delete argument tells rsync to delete files on the remote machine that don't exist on the local machine (e.x. files that I removed)

I use pub-private key authentication so the script runs without asking for a password. If you wish to use a password you will need to change

-e "ssh -l user1"

to

-e "sshpass -p password ssh -l user"

I could imagine you'd do something like this:

```
rsync -razv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '.settings' --exclude '.buildpath' -e "ssh -l user1" --delete ~/workspace/website/ www.server1.com:/var/www/
rsync -razv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '.settings' --exclude '.buildpath' -e "ssh -l user2" --delete ~/workspace/website/ www.server2.com:/var/www/
rsync -razv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '.settings' --exclude '.buildpath' -e "ssh -l user3" --delete ~/workspace/website/ www.server3.com:/var/www/
rsync -razv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '.settings' --exclude '.buildpath' -e "ssh -l user4" --delete ~/workspace/website/ www.server4.com:/var/www/
rsync -razv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '.settings' --exclude '.buildpath' -e "ssh -l user5" --delete ~/workspace/website/ www.server5.com:/var/www/
```

NOTE: sshpass will need to be installed on local machine if passwords are to be used. Rsync will need to be installed on the local and remote machines.

Comment: So would that mean that the rsync command would have to be run on the local machine not the production server?

Comment: Yes the commands you see above are run on the local machine and not the servers. You could however rewrite the rsync commands to run on the servers themselves and pull the latest files from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use git (http://git-scm.com/). You can create remotes for each of your servers (https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp). You can then push git repos to each of the servers.